# The closed form of sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, closed-form

I am looking for closed form of the sum:

$$\sum _{i=0}^{\infty } (-1)^i x^{\frac{1}{2} i (i k-k+2 n)}$$

we know the sum:

$$\sum _{i=0}^{\infty } (-1)^i x^{i k -k  + n}=\frac{x^{n-k}}{x^k+1}$$

I was trying to reach the first sum using the second one, but no success. So any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Your exponent is quadratic in $i$, so there is little hope of evaluating your new series in terms of that known series, where the exponent is linear in $i$.  The only series I know that have an exponent quadratic in the summation variable are the Jacobi theta functions.

Comment: Yes thanks, It should be related to Jacobi but not sure how to combine Theta functions to get this.